# How to add seperate layout and class to TabHost in android?

Tags: android

My base layout like follow

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="lk.abanservice.shankan.abansserviceapp.CheckStatus">

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/checkSerach"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/checkDisplayAll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

so i need to add following separate file and class to this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title_request"
    android:id="@+id/textViewTitleRequestt"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

i tried several ways to do this it can be do using TabActivity but that was removed from android 11. anyone has solution for that?

I want to develop following interfaces

[image] [image]

Comment: have you tried `<include />`

Comment: yes, via that only include xml only. But i need to do that for tab instigation. Could you please send me some sample for tab with action menu?

Comment: I added screen print what i need to do. Could you please send me sample code for that? need to work for Android Level 11 to higher only

Comment: Could you please point in your screen where you want to add your second layout?

Comment: I attached to images for same screen separate by Tab. 
"Job Search" is the main page in that page there are two tabs called "Check New Job" and "Check Old Job". I attached those interfaces. I need to do design those interfaces in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

This is Tab Host Example.. Change variables and class name according to your requirements...

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tab = getTabHost();

    TabSpec news = tab.newTabSpec("New");
    news.setIndicator("Check New Job");
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,First.class);
    news.setContent(intent);

    TabSpec old = tab.newTabSpec("Old");
    old.setIndicator("Check Old Job");
    Intent intent_old = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
    old.setContent(intent_old);

    tab.addTab(news);
    tab.addTab(old);
    }
 }
```

activity_main.java

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: Thank you, With extends "TabActivity" it deactivate top action menu. how to enable that? also TabActivity deprecated up to anadroid level 11

Comment: Which style you using?

Comment: add this style to your vlaues folder